# Problem executing a PostgreSQL SQL script on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sh

I would like to execute a SQL script that will create a database in Postgres. It produces the message:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

The script is:

```
 postgres@tom: /home/tom$ psql -1q test test <script.sql 2>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `2>` to actually do; it is definitely a syntax error. The proper redirection syntax is `2>filename` or `2>&n` where `n` is the number of an open file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect standard error to standard output, you should run

```sh
psql -1q -d test -U test -f script.sql 2>&1
```